# Reducing voltage using a resistor

Tags: rf

I want to know how to reduce an AC voltage of 175 V to 110 V using a resistor. The device I am using is 200 Watts, 110 V but the voltage from the source is 175 V. What value of resistor should I use to shed about 60 volts AC?

Comment: Where did you find a source of 175VAC?

Comment: It might help if you modify your question to be about the actual problem, rather than a proposed solution.  Why do you need to reduce the voltage?  What kind of device will you be plugging in?

Comment: A resistor is most likely a bad solution here.  Explain the real problem you are trying to solve and spare us your supposed solution.  That makes it easier to answer the question since bad assumptions don't have to be disspelled first.

Comment: I'd say a resistor is __definitely__ a bad solution here.

Comment: IMO 'definitely' is too strong. If this is a one-off limited-time hack a few light bulbs might be the most adequate solution. But as the TS has not mentioned what he wants to do this is pure speculation.

Comment: Actually, if it was resistive, a diode would be about right (123V RMS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your device is resistive (which might not be the case) and really draws 200 W (note that the type plate often states the maximum power drawn, which might not be the same) your device draws 200 W / 110 V = 1.8 A. The resistor must hence be 60 V / 1.8 A = 22 Ohm.

But here comes the catch: it must be able to dissipate 1.8 A * 60 V = 108 Watt!!

Your best approximation might be to use one or more 60V light bulbs, totaling ~ 108 Watt.

That was the literal answer, the more appropriate answer is: what is this for, do you really want to dissipate away 106 W in a resistor?